# SendSignedTransaction web3 v1.0 method call stack underflow

Tags: web3js, testrpc

When calling sendSignedTransaction I got:

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: stack underflow
```

Used code is below, using TESTRPC:

```
const serializeTx = async (contractInstance, publicKey, privateKey, funcData) => {
    let privateKeyBuff = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');

    const gasLimit = 500000;

    const nonceNumber = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(publicKey);
    const nonce = web3.utils.toHex(nonceNumber);
    const gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice);
    const gasLimitHex = web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit);
    const rawTx = {
        'nonce': nonce,
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
        'gasLimit': gasLimitHex,
        'from': publicKey,
        'to': contractInstance.address,
        'data': funcData
    };

    let tx = new EthereumTx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(privateKeyBuff);

    return '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
};

    let funcData = MyContract.methods.reserve(param).encodeABI();

        const serializedTx = await serializeTx(
            MyContract,
            body.callerPublicKey,
            body.callerPrivateKey,
            funcData,
        );

        let result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx);
```

Same contract function is working nice in Remix, also working nice when called using truffle-contract. Now when I try to sign the transaction data it throws 
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: stack underflow`

**EDIT**:
The problem was using `contractInstance.address` it should be `contractInstance._address`

Comment: It seems you are using web3 v1.0-beta, from their example you do not need to prefix the serialized transaction with '0x' https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#id67.

Comment: Just found out, the problem was in using contractInstance.address. In current version the address is under contractInstance._address. I will edit the question with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, and from what I could gather ([your comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28738/sendsignedtransaction-web3-v1-0-method-call-stack-underflow?newreg=317d7cff87d0460f8e55073ff9389bc9#comment30649_28738), [this comment](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/84#issuecomment-350563415) in an issue in ganache-cli and [this other](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/465#issuecomment-438438084)), `VM Exception while processing transaction: stack underflow` happens when the `to:` value is undefined or incorrect when trying to sign a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (and for others who follow) i encountered this error trying to estimate gas fees as follows:

```
var encodedData = tokenInst.methods._buyGuns(deadline).encodeABI();
var estimateGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    value: input_eth,
    data: encodedData,
    from: walletAddress
});
```

The problem was that because there is no "to: receiverAddress" in my estimateGas parameters it naturally interprets the transaction as contract creation, since there is no to, and executes the data provided is it were a constructor for a contract.

Solution: simply add a "to: " field in your transaction

```
var encodedData = tokenInst.methods._buyGuns(deadline).encodeABI();
var estimateGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    value: input_eth,
    data: encodedData,
    from: walletAddress,
    to: contractAddress});
```

Put simply in your case, `'to': contractInstance.address,` points to nothing or is null.